# Aggregating Count in Subquery in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basically I want Query 1 to give me the results of Query 2. I need to use Query 1 b/c I have other subqueries to add where I am either counting or getting max dates.

I tried Grouping By the `ClientVisit.client_id` in Query 1 but I get this error Column `'ClientVisit.clientvisit_id'` is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. `ClientVisit.clientvisit_id` isn’t in the Select list.

Query 1

```
SELECT ClientVisit.client_id ,
       ( SELECT COUNT( ZFORM_group_note_28.clientvisit_id )
         FROM ZFORM_group_note_28
         WHERE ZFORM_group_note_28.successful_day_752410 = 'Yes'
               AND ZFORM_group_note_28.clientvisit_id =        ClientVisit.clientvisit_id ) AS Successful_Day
FROM ClientVisit
WHERE ClientVisit.visittype_id = 16
      AND ClientVisit.program_id = 5
      AND ClientVisit.rev_timein >= @param1
      AND ClientVisit.rev_timeout < DATEADD( DAY ,
                                         1 ,
                                         @param2 )
```

Query 2

```
SELECT ClientVisit.client_id ,
       COUNT( ZFORM_group_note_28.clientvisit_id ) AS Successful_Day
FROM ClientVisit
INNER JOIN ZFORM_group_note_28
ON ZFORM_group_note_28.clientvisit_id = ClientVisit.clientvisit_id
WHERE ClientVisit.visittype_id = 16
      AND ClientVisit.program_id = 5
      AND ZFORM_group_note_28.successful_day_752410 = 'Yes'
      AND ClientVisit.rev_timein >= @param1
      AND ClientVisit.rev_timeout < DATEADD( DAY ,
                                         1 ,
                                         @param2 )
GROUP BY ClientVisit.client_id
```

Results:
Query 1

```
client_id   successful_day
1182    1
1182    1
1379    1
1379    1
1379    1
1379    1
```

Query 2

```
client_id   successful_day
1182    2
1379    9
1523    2
1757    1
```

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  The only reasonable way to get one row per *client* is to do an aggregation.  The table `clientvisit` has multiple rows per client.  The second query is the right solution.

Comment: I need to add in an additional count in the same query with `Zform_group_note28.successful_day_752410 = "No"`. I cannot do this as  Query 2 is written. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help. (Modified the query by using case statement)

```
select ClientVisit.client_id, sum(Successful_Day) as Successful_Day,Sum(Unsuccessful_Day) as Unsuccessful_Day
from
(
 SELECT ClientVisit.client_id ,
 Case when ZFORM_group_note_28.successful_day_752410 = 'Yes' then  COUNT(ZFORM_group_note_28.clientvisit_id ) else 0 end AS Successful_Day,
 Case when ZFORM_group_note_28.successful_day_752410 = 'No' then  COUNT(ZFORM_group_note_28.clientvisit_id ) else 0 end AS Unsuccessful_Day 
 FROM ClientVisit
 INNER JOIN ZFORM_group_note_28
 ON ZFORM_group_note_28.clientvisit_id = ClientVisit.clientvisit_id
 WHERE ClientVisit.visittype_id = 16
  AND ClientVisit.program_id = 5
  AND ClientVisit.rev_timein >= @param1
  AND ClientVisit.rev_timeout < DATEADD( DAY ,  1 , param2 )
 GROUP BY ClientVisit.client_id
)Clients
Group by ClientVisit.client_id
```

Comment: Edited.. forgot to write 'gorup by'.  please check the same.

Comment: Thank you. I caught the group by and added it in my query. The issue now is when I run the query, I get two rows for each client_id if they have both successful and unsuccessful days. @ munavvar

Comment: Edited. try this and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT ClientVisit.client_id ,
       COUNT( ClientVisit.clientvisit_id ) AS Successful_Day
FROM ClientVisit
INNER JOIN ZFORM_group_note_28
ON ZFORM_group_note_28.clientvisit_id = ClientVisit.clientvisit_id
WHERE ClientVisit.visittype_id = 16
      AND ClientVisit.program_id = 5
      AND ZFORM_group_note_28.successful_day_752410 = 'Yes'
      AND ClientVisit.rev_timein >= @param1
      AND ClientVisit.rev_timeout < DATEADD( DAY ,
                                         1 ,
                                         @param2 )
GROUP BY ClientVisit.client_id
```

All I have changed is the table name on the `COUNT` from `ZFORM_group_note_28` to `ClientVisit`.

Comment: Thank you. This provides the aggregation that I was able to get in Query 2. The issue is that I need to add in another count of `Zform_group_note28.successful_day_752410 = "No"` to get unsuccessful days.

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code I ended with that solved all the issues:

```
Select 
ClientVisit.client_id, 
Count(Case when ZFORM_group_note_28.successful_day_752410 = 'Yes' then 1  else null end) AS Successful_Day,
Count(Case when ZFORM_group_note_28.successful_day_752410 = 'No' then 1 else null end) AS Unsuccessful_Day

From ClientVisit 
Inner Join ZFORM_group_note_28 On ZFORM_group_note_28.clientvisit_id = ClientVisit.clientvisit_id 

Where ClientVisit.visittype_id = 16
AND ClientVisit.program_id = 5
And ZFORM_group_note_28.successful_day_752410 is not null
AND ClientVisit.rev_timein >= @param1
AND ClientVisit.rev_timeout < DATEADD( DAY ,  1 , @param2 )

Group By ClientVisit.client_id  

Order by ClientVisit.client_id
```